# Javascript true +/- true is false?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an expression to test if one field is null and treat is as false

```
a=true
b=true
-------------
true

 a=null
 b=true
 -------------
 true
```

but when I execute:

```
var a=true;
var b=true;
alert((a+b) == true);   => false
```

It returns false, i don't get it.

```
var a=null;
var b=true;
alert((a+b) == true);   => true
```

Comment: `true + true == 2` because `true` is the same as `1` (but not strictly). So of course `2 != true`

Comment: When you sum it via `a+b`, variables are converted to integers. `a+b` is 2. 2 is not `true` since `true` is converted to 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general solution for this in javascript is to use `!!` to parse to a boolean. `!!` negates the truthiness twice, resulting in a boolean which has the same truthiness of the original.

You should then use `&&` as a logical `and` operation.

```
var a=null;
var b=true;
console.log(!!a && !!b);   // false
```

#### Edit: An addendum on the strange `+` behaviour

The strangeness you're seeing when using `+` instead of `&&` is because, in JavaScript, `+` coerces booleans to integers, with `true` becoming `1` and `false` becoming `0`.

Hence

```
true + true \\ 2
true + false \\ 1
```

And then when doing

```
true + true == true
```

the left-hand-side of the equality comparison resolves to `2`, JavaScript then coerces the right-hand-side to `1` and thus the equality check fails.

When doing

```
null + true == true
```

the left-hand-side becomes the integer `1`, and then so does the right.

I'd recommend reading the [MDN guide on *Equality comparisons and sameness*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for more on JavaScript's value coercion and abstract equality checks.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = true;
var b = true;

console.log((a & b) === 1);

var c = null;

console.log((a & c) === 1);
```

`true == 1`
This is important. When you convert true to a number, it will be `1`

then `true + true == true` becomes `2 == 1`
which is `false`

similarly `null + true == true` becomes `1 == 1` which is true because `null` resolves to `0`

I think you are going about testing for `null` the wrong way.

try

```
alert((a & b) === 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For null and true to test to true you could probably do:

`!null === true`

This might solve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. When you are trying to make + operation `true` is like 1 and `false` is like 0. Then if you make `true+true` you get 2 and two is not 1, so it is not `true`.